# How to Configure Twilio Example project "account-security-quickstart-django" into my project

Tags: django-views, twilio, two-factor-authentication

I want to implement their existing project into my project . But I couldn't find out how to configure that .I just want to use their registration process without using their html . How can I configure that into my project ?

Comment: The quickstart application is just that, it is a small complete application that shows you how things go together. You don't configure it into your app, you use it as an example to write your own code for your own app. What have you tried so far to implement 2FA into your Django project? What errors are you coming across?

Comment: thanks . I had implemented twilio by using this application as an example .

Comment: Oh, glad to hear it is working!